# Confusion about roots of unity over a field of characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

In Exercise 13.6.4 of Dummit's & Foote's *Abstract Algebra*,
it is asked to:

> Prove that if $n=p^km$ where $p$ is a prime and $m$ is relatively prime to $p$
> then there are precisely $m$ distinct $n$th roots of unity over a field $F$ of
> characteristic $p$.

My question: Where exactly should the roots of $x^n-1$ be taken?
They can't be taken only in $F$.
For example, if $F=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $n=2\cdot 3$,
then there certainly do not exist 3 distinct roots of $x^6-1$ in $F$,
which only has 2 elements.

I've read a [solution](https://positron0802.files.wordpress.com/2021/01/algebra-13-dummit-1.pdf) to this exercise by [positrón0802](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/334676/positr%C3%B3n0802).
It roughly goes like this:

> Since $\text{char}\ F=p$, we have $x^n-1=(x^m-1)^{p^k}$,
> so the roots of $x^n-1$ are precisely the roots of $x^m-1$,
> which does not have any multiple root by considering its derivative.
> Hence, **the $\boldsymbol{m}$ distinct roots of $\boldsymbol{x^m-1}$ are precisely the $\boldsymbol{m}$ distinct $\boldsymbol{n}$th roots of unity over $\boldsymbol{F}$**.

The part in boldface seems to suggest that the roots are taken in the splitting field for $x^n-1$ over $F$.
Am I correct?
I don't manage to find a reference in the textbook about this.

Comment: Either $x^n-1$ or $x^m-1$ will do, yes. The point is that $x^m-1$ has no repeated roots in its splitting field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe we have:

Roots of unity *over* a field $F$ are elements of some large enough algebraic extension of $F$.

Roots of unity *in* a field $F$ are elements of the field itself.

So you can say that $\mathbb{F}_5$ 'has' a $4$th root of unity (Because $X^4-1=(X-1)(X+1)(X-2)(X+2)$ splits completely), and there 'exists' a $6$th root of unity *over* $\mathbb{F}_5$ (Because $X^6-1$ does not split completely).

There is no $6$th root of unity *in* $\mathbb{F}_5$, but there is a $6$th root of unity *over* $\mathbb{F}_5$.

I hope this makes sense.